# Reading smileys

Tags: readings, symbols

There are known English readings of smileys. For example:
`:-)`  is read as simply "smiley" according to Siri.
Sometimes Siri also calls it "colon hyphen close parenthesis".

But what about reading smileys in Japanese?
For example, I suppose that `:-)` would be "nikoniko" (just a wild guess)

Comment: "Known English readings"???  I don't know of any kind of agreed reading.  One might say something is  a smiley face, but that's a pretty broad generalization.  Siri might "think" one thing, but Siri is just a computer program.  Within a particular clique, there might be some uniformity in language.  But otherwise, I think this is too broad a question.  Any answer is more likely to be opinion based unless you somehow specify a particular context: such as when using my iPhone etc.

Comment: @A.Ellett I sometimes see smileys in email . I  didn't know how to read them. And what's more this is another problem when i comes to trying to read a newspaper aloud with smileys on it.

Comment: Most people don't read smileys as anything, I know I don't

Comment: @Angelos , Sometimes it appears in quotes, which means I do have to read it.

Comment: I agree with @Angelos.  When I see these things (like with most emojis) I don't read them as anything in particular.  They feel more like punctuation marks that convey a nuance of attitude and emotional content than something more tangible.  If it were necessary to describe them to someone, like :-P, I might just say say "someone sticking their tongue out at me".  So, a better question might not be to look for a universally agreed upon *word* but rather a *descriptive* phrase that others could understand.

Comment: When you see ! or other particular punctuation marks, like a hyphen or colon, you don't read those outloud.  At least, it's not customary to do so unless you're being pedantic and need to convey every single symbol from the text.  Is that what you need to do?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you provided an example of such a quote where you feel you need to enunciate the emoji itself.

Comment: Why would it appearing in quote mean you have to read it? It's not like a quote with an emoji was actually spoken aloud in the first place.

Comment: Under Windows, the emoji (絵文字) smileys have names.  Will that satisfy your question, or are you strictly looking for *emoticon* (顔文字) smiley names?

Answer (score 2):

`:-)` is not an universal symbol. Most Japanese people don't even notice it's a face. Naturally, there is no established way of reading it in Japanese.

The generic term to refer to faces using characters is *emoticon* or *smiley* in English, and 顔文字 (*kaomoji*, literally "face character") in Japanese. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon#Japanese_style).

IMEs often have "readings" for these kaomoji's (see [this page](http://www.hyou.net/a/ime-kaomoji.shtml) for examples), but these are merely input aids, and do not mean people read these out loud the same way. I think almost no one will read `(>_<)` as いたい.

A smiling emoji () is sometimes referred to as ニコニコマーク or ニコちゃんマーク, but it's rarely read out loud like this in practice, either.